# VS Code C++ Autocomplete user-defined not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

VS Code use to work perfectly fine. Now, whenever I type something such as "vec" and hit ctrl+space, no suggestions autocomplete. Similarly, my custom functions and variables do not autocomplete. I have also noticed the color for some types (such as string) used to be colored but is now white. Weirdly, it is colored if it is still defined outside the method, but it use to also be colored inside the method too:

[image]

However, autocomplete for these types come up: while, if, int, bool, for, etc. I am trying to get my VS Code to autocomplete like before, and if anyone can shine light on why this happened and how to fix it, that would be great! I do not believe I did anything out of normal usage. Note that I can still compile and execute.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did this so you can see the color as well, but I added that issue as an afterthought, so the title does not match this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a good advice in general - just not when the question is about the behavior of the IDE, and not the code per se.

Comment: @PranayAgrawal I get it now and agree. I've removed my initial comment.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik True - I've removed my comment.